# calling an angular controller method via ng-click in es6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class, angular-controller

I'm testing using es6 with angular 1.6 using browserify and babelify in gulp and I've noticed that when I create a controller using es6 class I can no longer call the controller's methods on the dom using ng-click.

**controller:**

```
    export default class FocusbtnsController {
    constructor($scope) {}

    testMethod() {
        alert('test method works!!');
    }
}
```

**main module:**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import FocusbtnsController from './focusbtns.controller';

export default angular.module('shapesite', [])
    .controller('FocusbtnsController', FocusbtnsController);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="center-btns ng-scope" ng-controller="FocusbtnsController">
    <div class="focus-btn-container" style="left:50%;top:5%" ng-click="testMethod()">
        <div class="diamond">
            <div class="diamond-btn"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried removing the `export default` from the `angular.module`, but with no effect.
when I add the method `testMethod` to the `$scope` argument `$scope.testMethod = testMethod;` it works, but it feels extremely dirty to do it that way.

I'm I missing something that will allow me to call the controller method while using the es6 syntax without having to assign it to the `$scope`?

Comment: If you're going to use 1.5+ I suggest you use components, which allow you to declare the controller for the view inside the component definition and you can call its methods by using `$ctrl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend on my comment, a simple Angular 1.5+ component would look like this.

**mycomponent.component.html**

```
<button ng-click="$ctrl.someMethod()">Click Me</button>
```

**mycomponent.component.js**

```
import template from './mycomponent.component.html';

class MyComponentController {
  constructor($filter) {
    'ngInject';

    this.$filter = filter;
  }

  someMethod() {
   console.log('Hello World');
  }
}

const myComponent = {
  template,
  controller: MyComponentController,
  bindings: {},
};
export default myComponent;
```

**mycomponent.module.js**

```
import myComponent from './mycomponent.component';

angular.module('MyModule')
  .component('myComponent', myComponent);
```

To use you can call `<my-component></my-component>`.

An alternative would be what Nicholas Tower answered, but again, in **my opinion** if you're using 1.5+ just use components.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use classes as a controller (or ES5 objects with prototypical inheritence for that matter), then you need to use controller-as syntax. This tells angular to use variables that are on the controller itself, rather than on $scope. So your template would change to this:

```
<div class="center-btns ng-scope" ng-controller="FocusbtnsController as $ctrl">
    <div class="focus-btn-container" style="left:50%;top:5%" ng-click="$ctrl.testMethod()">
        <div class="diamond">
            <div class="diamond-btn"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And i would recommend going one step further and using angularJS's Components, instead of ng-controller. See Baruch's answer for an example with components.